# Does the OpenID Connect Spec provide specifications for the design of the browser cookie?

Tags: http, security, cookies, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

The OpenID provider checks if a user is already authentication session created within the authorization server via a browser cookie.  Does the OpenID Connect spec contain design specifications / lock down the parameters for the implementation of the browser cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's considered out-of-scope for a protocol/interaction spec - which focuses on interoperability between peers - and left up to the implementer of the Authorization Server.